# Evitar que la app truene al convertir un String en Date

Tags: string, ios, swift, date

He tenido problemas al convertir String a Date, el problema radica en que recibo un valor `HH:mm` (cadena) y es necesario convertirlo a Date, entonces lo que hago es obtener el día actual, que es `2019-08-21`, después le concateno el valor de la cadena que recibo, más los segundos (`2019-08-21 12:00:00`) y lo convierto a Date, ahora, en algunos casos esa conversión truena, por lo que buscando un poco, le agregué .locale a mi formato.
Este es mi código:

```
        let currentDay = Date()
        let formatte = DateFormatter()
        formatte.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let dateFinishHour = formatte.string(from: currentDay)
        let finishTimeDate = dateFinishHour + " " + hourScheduled + ":00"
        //        para pasarlo a formato de Date
        let form = DateFormatter()
        form.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_MX")
        form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let dateRegister = form.date(from: finishTimeDate)
```

sin embargo `dateRegister` truena porque `finishTimeDate` regresa nulo (en algunos casos). ¿Alguna idea de cómo evitar esto?

Comment: porque usas formato de fecha cunado trabajas con horas. usa  `formatte.dateFormat = "HH::mm"` y con eso tienes el tiempo

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que necesito la fecha exacta (día actual), sin embargo del ws solo recibo la hora (aunque ya se que se trata del día actual), por lo que tengo que completar todo el valor, es por eso que convierto date a string, luego string a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes intentar lo siguiente para convertir el texto en tipo Date:

```
import Foundation

func dateFrom(_ dateString: String, format: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    guard let dateN = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    return dateN
}

let hora = "2019-08-21 12:00:00"
let dateFormat = dateFrom(hora, format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
print("\(dateFormat)")
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, me di cuenta que estaba haciendo algo mal en la funcionalidad, pero tu respuesta me ayudó muchisimo